# Oracle WebCenter change <!doctype in page template

Tags: oracle, jsf, portal, spaces, webcenter

I am new to Oracle WebCenter Portal.  I have a page template where the DOCTYPE specification is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

I need to change the doctype to:

```
<!doctype html>
```

I have been pulling out my hair for 2 days trying to figure out where to configure this.. and cannot seem to find it.  Note: I DO NOT want to manually edit each published page, I want to make this a global configuration.

I did find documentation on how to do this on older WebCenter version, but I am on:
**Oracle WebCenter Portal: Spaces Version 11.1.1.7.0** and the instructions for any documentation I have found does not show how to do it on this version.

To be honest, I would rather be pointed to an XML file I can directly edit, but if there is a way to do it in the WebCenter Adiministration panel that would be fine.

I will also need to add IE Emulation tags, but that is another topic.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: According to Oracle, this is impossible.. Gotta love Oracle.. I will try to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

This will be inside your page style, create your custom Page Style and add the doctype at the top.